# Formatting Array elements

Tags: perl

Hi I have an Array which looks like

```
@array = ( "city: chicago", "city: Newyork", "city: london", "country: india", "country: england", "country: USA")
```

I want the array to look like:

```
@array = ("city:", "chichago","Newyork","london","country:","india","england","USA")
```

Can anyone help me out how to format the array to look like the below format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splits every element of array by white spaces, and if `city:` or `country:` strings were already seen, it skips them, otherwise maps them as new elements together with city or country name,

```
my @array = ("city: chicago", "city: Newyork", "city: london", "country: india", "country: england", "country: USA");
my %seenp;
@array = map {
  my ($k,$v) = split /\s+/, $_, 2;
  $seenp{$k}++ ? $v : ($k,$v);
}
@array;
```

Comment: If the array is my @array = ("city: chicago", "city: Newyork", "city: london", "country: india", "country: england germany", "country: USA california");  Here In this case it is printing only the 1st part i.e., wahtever  it is there before the name (england germany ) here it is printing only england not "england germany".

Comment: That's how `split` works. To get "england germany" you'd have to change `my ($k, $v) = split;` to something like `my ($k, $v) = split /\s+/, $_, 2;`. This limits the `split` to produce only two groups.

Answer (score 1):

Why separate things out and stuff them back into a hard to use structure. Once you get them separated, keep them separated. They're much easier to work with that way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------

use charnames qw( :full :short   );
use English   qw( -no_match_vars );  # Avoids regex performance penalty

use Data::Dumper;

# Make Data::Dumper pretty
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent   = 1;

# Set maximum depth for Data::Dumper, zero means unlimited
local $Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = 0;

# conditional compile DEBUGging statements
# See http://lookatperl.blogspot.ca/2013/07/a-look-at-conditional-compiling-of.html
use constant DEBUG => $ENV{DEBUG};

# --------------------------------------


my @array = ( "city: chicago", "city: Newyork", "city: london", "country: india", "country: england", "country: USA");
my %hash = ();
for my $item ( @array ){
  my ( $key, $value ) = split m{ \s+ }msx, $item;
  push @{ $hash{$key} }, $value;
}

print Dumper \%hash;
```